# PHPMailer - OpenSSL Error

Tags: php, ssl, phpmailer

Based on the example that PHPMailer provides i have the script below,

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require './PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "myemail@example.com";
$mail->Password = "********";
$mail->setFrom('myMail@example.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addReplyTo('myEmail@example.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addAddress('toEmail@example.com', 'first last');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
$mail->Body = "example";
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

if (!$mail->send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Even if that is the exactly the same as the original example, i cannot get it to work.

The error that i get is

**Warning**: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in /opt/lampp/htdocs/webmail_client_practise/class.smtp.php on line 344
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

**Notice:** The OpenSSL extension in my `php.ini` file is already opened.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is because you're running PHP 5.6 and it's verifying your certs, but your server is presenting invalid certs so it's failing. Both PHPMailer and PHP are correct in what they are doing - the code is not at fault. You can either fix your mail server, or do what it suggests in [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting), which is:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

And as the guide says, *you should not do this unless you have to* - it's compromising your security.

Comment: Now every makes sense now! Thank you Synchro!

Comment: This helped. Thanks :)

Comment: NO - the right way to fix certificate errors is to install the certificate authority's signing cert in openssl - http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/others.shtml#ca-openssl

Comment: Did you actually read this answer, such as the bit where it says "you should not do this"? This answer is from a couple of years ago, when the most common cause of this error was **not** a missing or expired CA cert, but because the ISP was transparently redirecting SMTP traffic to their own server, causing certificate name mismatches, a specific case in which it's more reasonable to suppress the error in the way suggested. Just recently (Dec 2017), an out of date CA cert has been triggering the same error for gmail, which indeed would be better fixed by updating the CA cert, not suppressing.

Answer (score 10):

I was experiencing the exact same error as in the original question (yes 4 years later), and was able to solve it by changing the following within class.smtp.php (in both /includes/classes and /admin/includes/classes if they exist -- otherwise only in the PHPMailer main directory).

Change:

```
STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT
```

to:

```
STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT
```

It has to do with the updating of the TLS version in more recent PHP versions.

Source: https://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/410367-phpmailer-tls-12/

Comment: This should be the approved answer! Not compromising but improving security! +1

Comment: This was my problem as well - sending email via smtp.office365.com sometimes worked and sometimes didn't. It was completely random. This was my fix as well.

Comment: i also had the same issue with codeigniter-3. when trying to send email for mailtrap. now this solution worked for me

Comment: Had the same issue & this was the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Great!

It works fine for me too.

I updated PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (mail was working fine) to and
PHP Version 5.6.40-52+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (mail getting fail)

Now I just updated :-
STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT

TO

STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT

Now the mail is working fine.

Comment: It looks like this is intended to be a comment on [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694103/phpmailer-openssl-error/60609211#60609211). If an answer fixes your problem and you have helpful details of how you used the answer that you want to share, at 50 reputation you will be able to leave a comment with these details. Until then, comments on other answers shouldn't be submitted as new answers. You can get reputation by providing useful and detailed answers, asking clear and detailed questions, and suggesting helpful edits.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by reinstalling the ca-certificates package on my ubuntu server with:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`